# Vercel Cron job giving 504 error using nodemailer in nextjs

Tags: next.js, cron, vercel, nodemailer

So the problem is that i am using nodemailer to send email to users.
so nodemailer.js file is at root.

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: "ehtashamtoor50@gmail.com",
    pass: "mypasswordishere",
  },
});

export const mailOptions = {
  from: "ehtashamtoor50@gmail.com",
};
```

file path: api/setupReminder.js

```
import { mongooseConnect } from "@/lib/mongoose";
import { Task } from "@/models/Task";
import { mailOptions, transporter } from "@/nodemailer";

export default async function handle(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;

  await mongooseConnect();

  if (method === "GET") {
    const today = new Date();
    const todayStart = new Date(
      today.getFullYear(),
      today.getMonth(),
      today.getDate(),
      0,
      0,
      0
    );
    const todayEnd = new Date(
      today.getFullYear(),
      today.getMonth(),
      today.getDate(),
      23,
      59,
      59
    );
    const tasksWithReminders = await Task.find({
      "reminder.date": {
        $gte: todayStart,
        $lte: todayEnd,
      },
    }).populate("user");

    try {
      // Send email reminders for tasks with matching reminder dates
      tasksWithReminders.forEach(async (task) => {
        const newMailOptions = {
          ...mailOptions,
          to: task?.user?.email,
          subject: `Task Reminder: ${task.task}`,
          html: `<h1>Task Reminder</h1><p>Reminder for task "${
            task.task
          }" on ${task.reminder.date.toLocaleString()}</p>`,
        };

        transporter.sendMail(newMailOptions, (error, info) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
            res.send("All ok");
          }
        });
        // }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

this is my file vercel.json

```
{
    "crons": [
        {
            "path": "/api/setupReminder",
            "schedule": "30 16 * * *"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried above code. Maybe the issue is with hobby plan and my request is taking longer than 10 seconds. Can anyone help me out or tell me a way to implement this funtionality.
[this is the error i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrl52.png)

Answer (score 0):

The http status code indicates you are encountering is a gateaway timeout. Vercel returns this status code when a function takes longer to execute then the limit included in your plan.

[According to Vercel](https://vercel.com/blog/cron-jobs#included-resources-for-cron-jobs-and-vercel-functions) cron jobs duration limits are the same as Serverless and Edge Functions limits:

- Hobby: 10 seconds (Serverless), 30 seconds (Edge)
- Pro: 60 seconds (Serverless) 30 seconds (Edge)
- Enterprise: 900 seconds (Serverless), 30 seconds (Edge)